# PyQt5 Контекстное меню только на элементах QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np


class BaseApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        rootWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(rootWidget)

        boxSource = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.listSource = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.listSource.setHeaderLabels(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])

        self.listSource.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.listSource.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)
        boxSource.addWidget(self.listSource)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 200)
        resolution = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.move((resolution.width() / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2),
                  (resolution.height() / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2))

        for i1, i2, i3 in np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 3)):
            item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.listSource)
            item.setText(0, str(i1))
            item.setText(1, str(i2))
            item.setText(2, str(i3))

        rootWidget.setLayout(boxSource)

    def openMenu(self, position):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        addDes = QtWidgets.QAction('Add description', menu)
        addDes.triggered.connect(self.adddescript)
        menu.addAction(addDes)
        menu.exec_(self.listSource.viewport().mapToGlobal(position))

    def adddescript(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    root = BaseApp()
    root.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Клик совершен не на элементе]

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы контекстное меню появлялось только на элементах списка, а не во всей области виджета.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, для этого нужно в методе `openMenu` вызвать метод `self.listSource.itemAt(position)` и проверить на `None`. Если `None` то ничего не делать, а иначе показать меню.